# boolean env var in Github actions

Tags: github-actions

I have a boolean env var TAG_EVENT and I update it in one of the steps to false (I also print it and I see it false) but for some reason, the last step is not executed although TAG_EVENT is false. I appreciate help with that,

```
on:
 workflow_dispatch:

 env:
 TAG_EVENT: ${{ true }}

 jobs:
   push_images:
   name: Push images
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   if: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
   steps:
   - id: version
     name: Infer version
     run: |
        version="${GITHUB_REF#refs/tags/v}"
        echo $version
        if  [[ $version == refs/* ]] ;
         then
           echo 'TAG_EVENT=false' >> $GITHUB_ENV
           branch="${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}"
           version=$branch

       fi
       echo ::set-output name=version::$version
   - name: Publish latest image tag for release
     if: github.event_name != 'pull_request' && TAG_EVENT == false
     run: |
       echo "printme!!!"
```

Answer (score 4):

As you make use of a text-based shell like bash, you will have to deal with strings. Therefore you wont be able to do a check for `false`, but need to do it for `'false'`. But I would suggest marshaling the boolean by using GitHub's built-in `toJSON` and `fromJSON` functions:

```
...
steps:
  - name: I produce a boolean output
    id: output_producer
    shell: bash
    run: |
      if [[ $RANDOM > 100 ]]; then i=true; else i=false; fi
      echo "::set-output name=boolean_output::${{ toJSON($i) }}"
      echo "::set-output name=integer_output::${{ toJSON($i) }}"
  - name: I run conditionally on that boolean
    if: fromJSON(steps.output_producer.outputs.boolean_output) 
    shell: bash
    run: |
      echo "Ran successfully!"
  - name: I run always
    if: always()
    shell: bash
    run: |
      echo ${{ fromJSON(steps.output_producer.outputs.integer_output) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is some inconsistency between the input context and the way booleans are treated in GitHub Actions. I have a short write-up on this. Hope you find this helpful

[GitHub Actions: Passing Boolean input variables to reusable workflow_call](https://medium.com/@sohail.ra5/github-actions-passing-boolean-input-variables-to-reusable-workflow-call-42d39bf7342e?source=friends_link&sk=4b8a1d08f172674fc734aa6de701fec0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use in second if-statement `${{ env.TAG_EVENT == false }}`

Answer (score 1):

Per an updated GitHub blog, as of Nov-10-2021, for `workflow-dispatch` Actions, they support various new `types` in Conditions:

> You can now specify input types for manually triggered workflows... In addition to the default `string` type, we now support `choice`, `boolean`, and `environment`.

source: https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-10-github-actions-input-types-for-manual-workflows/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @zswqa answer this worked for me

```
env:    
  RUN_TESTS: ${{ true }}
```

Then in steps

```
- name: Gradle Test
  if: ${{ env.RUN_TESTS == 'true' }}
  run: gradle test
```

if I set `RUN_TESTS` to false then the test step doesn't run.